# Array java com indices alfanumericos

Tags: java

Feliz Natal a todos!

Como eu consigo, em **java**, esse **array**?

```
{
   "Aluno" => "fulano",
   "Idade" => 33
}
```

Pensei em **ArrayList,** mas não deu certo

Pensei em **List**, também não deu certo

Pense em **String[]** , mesma coisa

Parece que não aceitam **índices**.

Comment: Use `Map`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: Ou crie uma classe com os atributos que deseja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu caso o ideal seria um objeto que concentre esses atributos e uma lista deste objeto. Criei um caso de uso que pode se assemelhar com sua necessidade, uma classe Aluno, uma classe Turma com método de adicionar aluno:

Aluno.java

```
public class Aluno {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private String matricula;


    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
}
```

Turma.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Turma {

    private String codigo;
    private List<Aluno> alunos;


    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public List<Aluno> getAlunos() {
        return alunos;
    }

    public void setAlunos(List<Aluno> alunos) {
        this.alunos = alunos;
    }

    public void addAluno(Aluno aluno){
        if(this.alunos == null){
            this.alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
            this.alunos.add(aluno);
        }else{
            this.alunos.add(aluno);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Vai sera solução! Um objeto dá conta! Sou muito acostumado com PHP.